# Entry Save goes to error page after 5.3.2 Update

Tags: pages, headers

Starting after the 5.3.2 update, clicking on 'save' or "save and close" in an entry creates the following error output. The entry **does** save, but these warnings are confusing to users, since the page has no additional styles or links or confirmation that the save worked.

Extensive googling on the subject has turned up nothing, so I'm wondering if its a new bug.

**Error Page Content:**

```
**Notice**
Undefined index: pages__pages_uri
ee/EllisLab/Addons/pages/tab.pages.php, line 155

Severity: E_NOTICE

**Warning**
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 238

Severity: E_WARNING

**Warning**
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 238

Severity: E_WARNING

**Warning**
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php, line 393

Severity: E_WARNING
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the Pages addons.  Are you using it?  Looks like the page uri (not the url_title) is causing the error

Comment: @BenoitL , thanks for the reply! I am use the Pages addon, but not for this channel. It looks like the channel that DOES use the Pages addon has no problems--only those channels that DO NOT use the add throw the error on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this pull request on github: https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/pull/412

Basically-  system/ee/EllisLab/Addons/pages/tab.pages.php around line 155:

```
if ($data['pages__pages_uri'] == '' OR $data['pages__pages_uri'] == lang('example_uri')) {

change to

if (empty($data['pages__pages_uri']) OR $data['pages__pages_uri'] == lang('example_uri')) {
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: PERFECT! This fixes the problem. Marking as solution.